# Redshift Work Load Management rules implication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How can I set up a Workload Management rule for CPU Utilization for my Amazon Redshift cluster for 75% usage?

It shows values more than 100.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more information? For example, where does it "show values more than 100"? What do you mean by "rule...for 75% usage"? What behaviour are you wanting to achieve.

Comment: Hey Whenever i check in the SVL_QUERY_METRICS_SUMMARY table of the redshift and check for the values of query_cpu_usage_percent  metric ,it shows values of per cent more then 100.. I am not clear about these numbers

Answer (score 0):

The [WLM Query Monitoring Rules - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-wlm-query-monitoring-rules.html) documentation says:

> `query_cpu_usage_percent`
>   Percent of CPU capacity used by the query. Valid values are 0–6,399.

Therefore, it seems that it goes up to 64 CPUs.

100% would represent one CPU-equivalent fully used. 200% would represent two CPUs fully used.